# Is taking logs to vectorize repeated multiplication the right approach?

Tags: r, matlab, machine-learning, linear-algebra, vectorization

I recently wrote an implementation of Naive Bayes to classify examples into one of 5 different groups. The number of features n was very large, and each feature could be on (1) or off (0). Using the training set, I estimated an 5 × n matrix P of conditional probabilities for each group G<sub>i</sub> against each feature F<sub>j</sub>, for 1≤i≤5, 1≤j≤n, so that cell (i,j) = P(G<sub>i</sub>=1|F<sub>j</sub>=1). (I'm ignoring the probabilities P(G<sub>i</sub>=1|F<sub>j</sub>=0) as they aren't relevant to this discussion.)

What I wanted to do was, given a new example E, a 1 × n vector, multiply together the conditional probabilities from the matrix P corresponding to features which were on in the new example. I had two concerns in doing this:

1. the very large number of features means that a loop would be very slow
2. repeated multiplication might lead to loss of accuracy

What I did was to take the log of P, L=log(P) and then perform the matrix multiplication E L'. The multiplication gives a 1 × 5 result and the maximum of the result indicates which group, assuming prior probabilities about equal. This solves the speed issue through vectorization and the accuracy issue by taking logs (and, of course, taking logs transforms multiplication to addition). Another advantage is that E L' would work for a set of training examples where E was a matrix rather than a vector.

My question is, is taking logs like this a reasonable / standard approach? It seems like it might be the obvious, "101" approach, but I have limited experience of implementing algorithms like this so I would appreciate feedback from those with more experience.

---

For reference, in the Naive Bayes approach, Bayes theorem gives the probability of being in group g conditional on features **F**= **f** as

> P(G=g|**F**= **f** ) = P(**F**= **f**|G=g)P(G=g) / P(**F**= **f** )

Expanding the features vector **F** into F<sub>1..n</sub> gives

> P(G=g|F<sub>1</sub>= f<sub>1</sub>, F<sub>2</sub>= f<sub>2</sub>... F<sub>n</sub>= f<sub>n</sub>) = P(F<sub>1</sub>= f<sub>1</sub>, F<sub>2</sub>= f<sub>2</sub>... F<sub>n</sub>= f<sub>n</sub>|G=g)P(G=g) / P(**F**= **f** )

Applying the Naive assumption of independent features

> P(G=g|F<sub>1</sub>= f<sub>1</sub>, F<sub>2</sub>= f<sub>2</sub>... F<sub>n</sub>= f<sub>n</sub>) = P(F<sub>1</sub>= f<sub>1</sub>|G=g) P(F<sub>2</sub>= f<sub>2</sub>|G=g) ... P(F<sub>n</sub>= f<sub>n</sub>|G=g)P(G=g) / P(**F**= **f** )

The denominator can be dropped as it's the same for all g, so we have

> P(G=g|F<sub>1</sub>= f<sub>1</sub>, F<sub>2</sub>= f<sub>2</sub>... F<sub>n</sub>= f<sub>n</sub>) ∝ P(F<sub>1</sub>= f<sub>1</sub>|G=g) P(F<sub>2</sub>= f<sub>2</sub>|G=g) ... P(F<sub>n</sub>= f<sub>n</sub>|G=g)P(G=g)

Here, P(G=g) is the prior probability.

Comment: without answering your question, you can test the accuracy of your approach using the Rmpfr Package:  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/vignettes/Rmpfr-pkg.pdf

Comment: @natan thanks, I was trying to do it long-hand to educate myself as to the mechanics, but that will be useful for next time (and would have been useful as a check!).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have rewritten the multiplication of E P' to deal with the fact that you're representing P by log(P)?

Representing conditional probabilities with logs of probabilities is a very common technique to work around the fact that they can get so freaking small.

Many of the implementations of robust classifiers in automatic target recognition applications (i.e. Dempster-Schafer for instance) force probabilities to always be non-zero.  What you're proposing is another way at getting that.

Comment: yes, thanks, I've corrected my post to read E L' not E P'. (Also, I needed to take the transpose to get (e×n) × (n×5) where e is the number of training examples.) When I was estimating the conditional probabilities in P I followed the procedure of using a very small probability for the case where for a given feature was always off for a particular group (I used 1/m^2, where m was the number of training examples).

Comment: Note:  exp( E log(P') ) is not the same as E P'.  So, when I say rewrite, I mean you have to perform the computation quite a bit differently.  It looks like you've not taken that into account in your expression above.

Comment: thanks. With Naive Bayes, the original calculation wouldn't be `E P'`. Considering the case when `E` is 1 × n, you would first project `P`, which is 5×n, in the SQL sense, by selecting those columns of `P`, `P_i` where `E_i=1`, to give a 5×N matrix, `N<n`. Then you would multiply the resulting probabilities on each row  together to get a 5×1 matrix and identify the maximum probability. By taking logs I can use matrix multiplication in a way I wasn't able to before. Moreover because `exp` is monotonic increasing I don't need to apply `exp` to identify the max.