# Implementation options to determine whether news is good news or bad news

Tags: algorithm, sorting, machine-learning

Last week I developed a simple news reader with jQuery, parsing a JSONP and inserting the generated list into the flow of a web page. This morning I have been asked this question: "Is there a sort of intelligent algorithm that is able to 'understand' if a news is bad, good, or neutral?" My answer..."Well...I don't have idea."...That's why I am asking this question: is there a way to implement such thing? THe only thing I can thing about is checking if the title contains words like "killed,bomb,assassin,flood,earthquake,tsunami,..." and similar...Any other idea? Do you know if similar solutions have been already implemented? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is called [Sentiment analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis). There should be plenty of scientific publications around this topic.

Comment: "Assassin was killed, victim survived"

Comment: Take a look here: [http://www.uclassify.com/browse/uClassify/Sentiment](http://www.uclassify.com/browse/uClassify/Sentiment).

Comment: Tsunami relief effort saved hundreds of children left homeless after killer earthquake with the strength of several atomic bombs triggers megaflood.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a classification algorithm. There are many different choices, e.g. see [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/talks/picasso-minicourse.pdf). A well-known one, and an easy one to implement to start off with, is [Naive Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier).

In Naive Bayes, you look at the frequencies of words appearing in news items that you have already judged to be bad, and also at the frequencies of those words appearing in news items you have already judged to be good. These give you an estimate of the conditional probabilities P(word|good) and P(word|bad), i.e. probability of seeing a word given good news, and probability of seeing a word given bad news.

When you see a new news item, you work out what words are and are not in the news item, and use Bayes theorem to give you P(good|words) and P(bad|words), essentially by multiplying together the probabilities you calculated above of the words appearing or not appearing in your news article, together with how often you expect good or bad news. If P(good|words) > P(bad|words) then it's good news. (I put some of the maths in a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030793/is-taking-logs-to-vectorize-repeated-multiplication-the-right-approach) I wrote a while back if you're interested; however there are much better sources on the web and in books.)

Naive Bayes is a well-known technique and is also used in spam filtering. It's interesting as well because of what it doesn't address. In particular, it takes no account of the ordering or context or words. So "There were no hurricanes this week" might be good news despite containing the work "hurricane". I'd guess that such considerations are probably more important in analyzing news articles than tweets, for example. In any case, it's an interesting field and there has been a lot of work done already.

Comment: Thank you TooTone, this is really interesting and helpful, most of all, as you say at the end, when judging news articles that will likely contain words like "hurricane" "tsunami" or similar. I am defintely going to give it a read, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here it's done for twitter, it's called sentiment analysis.

http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/healey/tweet_viz/tweet_app/

http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/healey/tweet_viz/

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at it!

Comment: Cool, hope that I answered your question since it was quite broad (which I understand why)

Comment: I am not sure if sentiment analysis is what OP is asking for, SA is great to classify the emotions implicit in a text. However, commonly news are written in a neutral sentiment.

Comment: But you could use the same strategy not listening to "sentiment-words" but instead listen to words you classify as "positive vs negative". I know there are similar tools used by stock traders, don't know the name though.

Answer (score 1):

a series algorithms to handle this are called [supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning), which belong to [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning).

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at it!

Comment: While this is correct, supervised learning is a very broad field. E.g. you can consider linear regression to be a supervised learning technique. At the very least you might want to narrow the field down to classification algorithms.